# C#: Inheritance Problem with List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, list

Let's assume this class in C#:

```
public class LimitedList<T> : List<T>
{
    private int _maxitems = 500;

    public void Add(T value) /* Adding a new Value to the buffer */
    {
        base.Add(value);
        TrimData(); /* Delete old data if lenght too long */
    }

    private void TrimData()
    {
        int num = Math.Max(0, base.Count - _maxitems);
        base.RemoveRange(0, num);
    }
}
```

The compiler gives me this warning in the line "public void Add(T value)":

> warning CS0108: 'System.LimitedList.Add(T)' hides inherited member 'System.Collections.Generic.List.Add(T)'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

What do I have to do to avoid this warning?

Thx 4 your help

Comment: Don't forget to override the behavior of the rest of the interface also if your going to use inheritance.  Otherwise you just need to make a collection that Has a collection, not is a collection.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No - **don't** use `new` here; that doesn't give you polymorphism. `List<T>` isn't intended for inheritance in this way; use `Collection<T>` and `override` the <s>`Add`</s> `InsertItem` method.

```
public class LimitedCollection<T> : Collection<T>
{
    private int _maxitems = 500;

    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
        TrimData(); /* Delete old data if lenght too long */
    }

    private void TrimData()
    {
        int num = Math.Max(0, base.Count - _maxitems);
        while (num > 0)
        {
            base.RemoveAt(0);
            num--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a much better explanation on how to properly code this. Thanks Marc

Comment: than i have to implement the whole interface ?!

Comment: @Bigbohne, yes.  You would have to forward all of the calls into your class

Comment: @JaredPar - not if you inherit from Collection<T> (which does all that forwarding for you to the base IList<T>)

Comment: @Marc, I think that even inheriting from Collection is wrong because it's violating an implicit controct.  I would expect anything I add to a Collection<T> via Add to be available until I 1) lose control of the object or 2) explicitly remove it.  LimitedCollection would violate this contract

Comment: @JaredPar - hmmm... indeed, I can't argue with that; I guess it depends what the OP is trying to achieve. But it certainly beats `new` ;-p

Comment: @Marc, agreed it's better than new because it's at least provides a consistent experience no matter what reference type is used to view the object.  IMHO, I think the best approach is to wrap List<T>, implement IEnumerable<T> and pretty much nothing else.  There doesn't seem to be any collection style interface other than IEnumerable<T> where LimitedList would not violate an implicit contract.

Comment: @all, I just want to Plot realtime data. A "normal" list is fine but growing until "infinity". If you guys know better aproache for this. pls tell me.

Comment: TBH I'd just create a new generic class called LimitedList<of T> with an associated interface and be happy :p

Comment: It sounds like you actually want a ring buffer for your numbers. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer

Comment: a ring buffer is something different. although this would also look cool :)

Answer (score 11):

You can avoid this warning by adding "new" to the declaration.

```
public new void Add(T value) { 
 ...
}
```

However I think you may be approaching this problem a bit wrong by using Inheritance.  From my perspective LimitedList is not a List because it expresses very different behavior as it puts a hard constraint on the amount of data in the List.  I think it would be much better to not inherit from List but have a List as a member variable.

Another reason why this is a bad idea is that you won't be able to satisfy your class's contract when it is viewed as a List.  The following code will use the List`s Add method and not LimitedList.

```
List<int> list = new LimitedList<int>(10);
for ( i = 0; i < 10000; i++ ) {
  list.Add(i);
}
```

Comment: @Marc completely agree this is wrong.  I added an example of where this is broken.

Comment: @Dan agreed, this is why inheritance is bad here.

Comment: +1, agreeing that it would be much better to encapsulate a List<T> instance instead of inheriting from it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your 'Add' method as a 'new' (replacement) method.
Try this:

```
public class LimitedList<T> : List<T>
{
    private int _maxitems = 500;

    public new void Add(T value) /* Adding a new Value to the buffer */
    {
        base.Add(value);
        TrimData(); /* Delete old data if length too long */
    }

    private void TrimData()
    {
        int num = Math.Max(0, base.Count - _maxitems);
        base.RemoveRange(0, num);
    }
}
```

notice the 'new' keyword in the 'Add(...' declaration.

**Although, in this instance, you should create your own generic class implementing the IList interface.**
Hope that helps.

Comment: See the other replies about polymorphism to see why this isn't a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

Like others have stated, you need to add the new keyword. The reason for this is because in the base class (List<T>)  the Add method hasn't been marked with the keyword "virtual" which basically means "overridable". Therefore, it should be marked as "new".