# Namespace error for Generic list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a link list code, where I am using a line

```
 GenericList<int> gll = new GenericList<int>();
```

But it shows namespace is missing, I have added `system.collection` and `system.collection.generic`

I Google it, but I am unable to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What really is a `GenericList` ? Your custom collection type?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, there is no `GenericList<T>` type in the .NET Framework.
Instead, use `List<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not so much an answer to the question but some interesting information about creating your own custom XxxxxList<>-style collections:

[Inheriting from List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376203/inherit-listt)

[C#: Inheritance Problem with List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898152/c-inheritance-problem-with-listt)

(I'm assuming your GenericList class was created by a coworker, and maybe he/she did it the right way, or maybe the wrong way.)